# Issue with Swipe Gesture Control in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, gesture

In my application I am using Swipe Gesture Control.I have a table view and a view controller.
my view design will be like :-[image][image]
When swipe the itwill works great.but problem is that when swipe speedly it will some times display as overlapped bar buttons
[image]
What will be the solution.I just tried this code

```
 if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

}
```

also i have used the code for hide back button in table view
 It Not be worked on my project.pls help me

Comment: can you please try the following: 

`[mySwipeGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer]` inside the if case.

Comment: It not worked.again show same bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post this code in view controller in viewDidLoad..

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
swipeLeft.direction =UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight =[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
swipeRight.direction =UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

Put methods for swipeLeft: and swipeRight:

Hope this will help you..

Code for swipeLeft: and swipeRight:

```
-(IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender
{
            CView *view =[[CView alloc]initWithNibName:@"CView" bundle:Nil];
            CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:NO];
            [animation setDuration:0.30];
            [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
            [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
            [[view.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"CView"];
}
-(IBAction)swipeRight:(id)sender
{
        EView *view =[[EView alloc]initWithNibName:@"EView" bundle:Nil];
        view.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];;
        [view release];
}
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: this methods are not calling when swipe

Comment: @PraphinSP put the code in view controller's viewDidLoad and put the two methods for changing the views it will work..

Comment: It will move faster to view controller i just tried following code -(void)swipeLeft:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: Pls specify CView and EView

Comment: This is xib names you have to provide yours..
or you can apply it for current view.. 
This is just example you have to put your own code
@PraphinSP

Comment: But i want the view is like in this tutorial http://www.imore.com/top-5-secret-ios-7-gestures-how-get-more-done-faster

Comment: @PraphinSP in ios7 it is default layout no need to set anything..
just add navigation controller to root view controller from AppDelegate..

Answer (score 0):

Use following methods. It will call when you swipe

Hope this will help you.

```
- (void)swipeLeft:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    // Insert your own code to handle swipe left
}
- (void)swipeRight:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // Insert your own code to handle swipe right
}
```